# Adding multiple JTextfields with Absolute Position

Tags: java, jtextfield, absolute

I'm currently doing a course in java programming and the project involves making a calculator for a restaurant. We have to position all the GUI elements using absolute position. My project is coming together alright (I think). I am just having difficulty adding numerous `JTextfields` to the GUI, every time [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGW3N.jpg) I add on and put in the X&Y coordinates it is not adding the second or third `JTexfield`, instead it is just moving the first `JTextfield` to the last defined position. I am not 100% sure if I am explaining this correctly so I have attached screenshots of the problem.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class RestaurantCalculator {
     public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane){
        pane.setLayout(null);

       JLabel Welcome = new JLabel("Restuarant");
              Welcome.setBounds(250, 5, 150, 100);
              Welcome.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 20));


       JLabel Waiter = new JLabel("Waiter Information");
          Waiter.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 100);
          Waiter.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 14));

   JLabel Tableno = new JLabel("Table number:");
          Tableno.setBounds(120, 130, 200, 100);
          Tableno.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));


   JLabel WaiterName = new JLabel("Waiter Name:");
          WaiterName.setBounds(120, 160, 200, 100);
          WaiterName.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel MenuItems = new JLabel("Menu Items");
           MenuItems.setBounds(100, 220, 150, 100);
           MenuItems.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel Beverage = new JLabel("Beverage:");
           Beverage.setBounds(120, 250, 200, 100);
           Beverage.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel Appetizer = new JLabel("Appetizer:");
           Appetizer.setBounds(120, 280, 200, 100);
           Appetizer.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel MainCourse = new JLabel("Main Course:");
           MainCourse.setBounds(120, 310, 200, 100);
           MainCourse.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel Dessert = new JLabel("Dessert:");
           Dessert.setBounds(120, 340, 200, 100);
           Dessert.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel SubTotal = new JLabel("Sub Total:");
           SubTotal.setBounds(120, 440, 200, 100);
           SubTotal.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel Tax = new JLabel("Tax:");
           Tax.setBounds(120, 470, 200, 100);
           Tax.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel Total = new JLabel("Total:");
           Total.setBounds(120, 500, 200, 100);
           Total.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));


    JTextField Table = new JTextField(10);
           Table.setBounds(290, 171, 150, 20);


   pane.add(Welcome);       
   pane.add(Waiter);
   pane.add(Tableno);
   pane.add(WaiterName);
   pane.add(MenuItems);
   pane.add(Beverage);
   pane.add(Appetizer);
   pane.add(MainCourse);
   pane.add(Dessert);
   pane.add(SubTotal);
   pane.add(Tax);
   pane.add(Total);
   pane.add(Table);

}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Restaurant Bill Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane.
    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //Size and display the window.
    Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
    frame.setSize(600 + insets.left + insets.right,
                  700 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Most people will disagree, but if you are using eclipse there is a windowbuilder plugin for generating GUI code with GUI.

Comment: As I can see you are not adding more JTextFields in this code, you should get memory for each of them (with new keyword) also variable names should start with lowercase letter by convention.

Comment: I know in the example I didn't demonstrate the adding of an additional textfield to the pane but everytime I do it alters the Table textfield instead of adding an additional one to the GUI

Comment: Alerts means syntax error? Maybe you could provide us what exactly it says, and maybe the code that caused it? You can not name 2 text fields the same.

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error its just positioning the Table textbox to in the new declared position for a textbox called WName....here is the code I am using to add a Textfirld called WName to the GUI pane... JTextField WName = new JTextField(10);               WName.setBounds(290, 201, 150, 20);Then I add to pane...pane.add (WName);

Comment: I mean its not giving me a syntax error...just repositioning the Table textfield

Comment: Maybe you could provide a code of the problem.

Comment: Here's the code....they have different names so it's not that...confusing/annoying...import java.awt.Container;import java.awt.Insets;import javax.swing.JFrame;import javax.swing.JLabel;import java.awt.Font;import javax.swing.JTextField;import javax.swing.JButton;public class RestaurantCalculator {     public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane){        pane.setLayout(null);       JLabel Welcome = new JLabel("Restuarant");              Welcome.setBounds(250, 5, 150, 100);              Welcome.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 20));                                 JLabel Wai

Comment: There seems to be a limit on the text i can put up on this :-( annoying

Comment: You can edit your post.

Comment: TextField Table = new JTextField(10);               Table.setBounds(290, 171, 150, 20);                       JTextField WName = new JTextField(10);               WName.setBounds(290, 201, 150, 20);                                                      pane.add(Welcome);              pane.add(Waiter);       pane.add(Tableno);       pane.add(WaiterName);       pane.add(MenuItems);       pane.add(Beverage);       pane.add(Appetizer);       pane.add(MainCourse);       pane.add(Dessert);       pane.add(SubTotal);       pane.add(Tax);       pane.add(Total);       pane.add(Table);       pane.add(WNam

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/WXDvsZkv) code works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah I know...I think I fixed it without noticing...cheers anyway